# how to solve problem page numbering

Tags: page-numbering

I am writing my thesis via LaTeX and I have written list of abbreviation and it is 2 pages.

I used page numbering `\begin{termlist}` and `\end{termlist}`. However, my introduction section starts from page 2 instead of one. the page numbering should generate VI and after that VII. Nonetheless, it is VI and 1.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Hi. Please add an MWE to help us help you!

Comment: You're probably issuing `\pagenumbering{arabic}` not preceding it by `\cleardoublepage`.